# Call a function within a function to init

Tags: jquery, function, variables, plugins, init

```
;(function ($, w, d, config, undefined) {
$.fn.pluginName = function ( options, config ) {
    var pluginName = this;
    var defaults = {
        //defaults
    };
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var methods = {
        init :  function ( settings, options ) {
            //init stuff here
        }
    }
})
})(jQuery, window, document)

// HTML looks like this
<script>
$('.item').pluginName({ methods : 'init' });
</script>
```

I'm new to plugin development, and objects in general, but I'm trying to learn in the deep end without swimmies.  :)

Basically, I want to initialize my plugin by calling the "init" function within the methods variable. My plugin's name is "pluginName".

I am having trouble calling the "init" fn because it lives within a variable named "methods".

Also, to take this one step further, I need to collect all the "item" classes on the page and set the inside a data variable.  In my init function I have the following:

```
return this.each(function(){

    var $this       = $(this),
    data        = $this.data('pluginName');

    if ( ! data ) {
        $(this).data('pluginName', {
        target : $this
        });

    }
}).bind(this);
```

The above returns "this.each is not a function"

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it so you don't have to pass in an object for method calls, I usually use this format:

```
(function($) {
    function doSomething() {
        // Only callable in this plugin's context (I think)
    }

    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            // Do whatever for init!
            doSomething();
        },

        anotherMethod: function (options) {
            // Some other method
            doSomething();
        }
    };

    $.fn.pollServer = function(method) {
        var args = arguments;
        var argss = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1);

        return this.each(function () {
            $this = $(this);
            if (methods[method]) {
                methods[method].apply($this, argss);
            }
            else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
                methods.init.apply($this, args);
            }
            else {
                $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jQuery.pollServer");
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And you access it like:

```
$("#div").pollServer({});
$("#div").pollServer("init", {}); // Same as above line

$("#div").pollServer("anotherMethod", {});
```

Everything inside of return this.each() determines what method to call, and set the "this" variable as the jQuery element selected. It also passes additional arguments to the methods.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is BRILLIANT!! Thank you! I will work with this. I've already written a different pattern but yours seems much more logical. I will comment again once I've implemented your solution and let you know how it works!  Thanks so very much for this!

Comment: No problem! I found something similar somewhere on the jQuery website, but modified it some to do what I want. It's worked for me, so I hope it helps you! Let me know if you need more guidance with something like this

Comment: Okay, so I don't want to start getting messy with my code. The init function works beautifully, THANK YOU!  So I have two new questions and I think I'm GOLDEN...  

First of all. **How do I call a function from within "init"?** Remembering that it is within the "methods" variable.  

**Also, how would I call a function from within "pollServer()"**, again, using the functions within "methods" variable?

Any examples you can give with argument passing would be greatly aprpeciated! You've already helped me LOADS! THANK YOU!

Comment: I've added the code below for better reference. It's not 100%, I have different files saved with other functional parts. Once I am able to figure this out, I will be able to add those functions :)